# How to add Stack-panel to Datagrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a data grid and I am trying to add a stack panel to the first cell of each row in my data grid programmatically using WPF. But the problem is that when I do that then the value in the cell appears as text value "Syetem.Windows.Controls.StackPanel". I am trying to do just as this sample datagrid[image]

but what happend now is that the ellipse is not shown for some reason
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAAFh.png)

My XAML for my datagrid

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" AlternationCount="2"  Margin="66,332,0,8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="984">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,5,1"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Tag Name" Width="150">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="stackEllipse" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Ellipse x:Name="myEllipse" Width="10" Height="10" Fill="{Binding Color}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tag_Name}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <!--  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag Name" Width="150" Binding="{Binding Path = Tag_Name}"/> -->
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag Comment" Width="250" Binding="{Binding Path = Tag_Comment}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Width="150" Binding="{Binding Path = Value}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit" Width="150" Binding="{Binding Path = Unit}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lower" Width="150" Binding="{Binding Path = Lower}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Upper" Width="150" Binding="{Binding Path = Upper}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

My Backend

```
   
        string[] Colors = {"#1E3B6B", "#1859A9", "#0773D7", "#E32726", "#A9343A","#008000","#006400","#FF00FF","#ff8243","#7f00ff","#add8e6","#4D5156",
           "#291446", "#FAA22C", "#EE7623", "#FCE300",
           "#E6B3B3", "#6680B3", "#66991A",
          "#FF99E6", "#CCFF1A", "#FF1A66", "#E6331A", "#33FFCC",
          "#66994D", "#B366CC", "#4D8000", "#B33300", "#CC80CC",
          "#66664D", "#991AFF", "#E666FF", "#4DB3FF", "#1AB399",
          "#E666B3", "#33991A", "#CC9999", "#B3B31A", "#00E680",
          "#4D8066", "#809980", "#E6FF80", "#1AFF33", "#999933",
          "#FF3380", "#CCCC00", "#66E64D", "#4D80CC", "#9900B3",
          "#E64D66", "#4DB380", "#FF4D4D", "#99E6E6", "#6666FF" };

        public string Color { get; set; } = "#1E3B6B";


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public class Table
        {
            public string Tag_Name { get; set; }
            public string Tag_Comment { get; set; }
            public float Value { get; set; }
            public string Unit { get; set; }
            public float Lower { get; set; }
            public float Upper { get; set; }

        }

 private void FillDataGrid()
        {
            

            for (int ControllersListSize = 0; ControllersListSize < ControllersList.Count; ControllersListSize++)
            {


                datagrid_List.Add(new Table {Tag_Name = "  " + (ControllersListSize + 1 ) + "   " +  ControllersList[ControllersListSize], Tag_Comment = "", Value = 8, Unit = "kj/h", Lower = 9, Upper = 28 });
                Color = Colors[ControllersListSize]; // here I update the Color property with using the array of colors.
                OnPropertyChanged("Color");

            }

            dataGrid.ItemsSource = datagrid_List;



        }
```

Comment: Use a [DataGridTemplateColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) with a CellTemplate that contains an Ellipse element.

Comment: @Clemens Actually I was trying this way and the ellipse was shown but until I reached to a point that I did not know the right way to bind 'Fill' to each ellipse, I tried to give the ellipse name but it was weird when I found that it  in the code behind I cannot call it! it was telling me that "name does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Bind the Color property of a SolidColorBrush in the Ellipse's Fill to a property of your view model item class. If necessary, with a Binding Converter.

Comment: @Clemens if you can give me a sample how to do it, I will be really thankful. Cause I know the binding part but I do not know how to do it with the ellipse ... I mean how to call the ellipse and give it the color

Comment: It is unclear how you would select a specific color from the `Colors` array, but see the answer for how you would proceed with an appropriate property in the item class.

Comment: @Clemens I have Updated my code with your sample code, In my for loop I need to update each ellipse in each row with the color in my Colors array

Comment: If you see my sample in the first image I want to do exactly the same, and my Colors are in my array that's all

Comment: The Color property is meant to be declared in the Table class.